# .htaccess file work fine on localhost but generates 404 error on testing server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am developing a system which redirects all requests to an index.php file using .htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex public/index.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).+)$ public/index.php?cmd=$1  [QSA,NC,L]
```

Which works fine when I am running the system locally via XAMPP but when I upload it to a remote testing site, its only able to load the homepage but when I click any other link it generates a 404 error.

What could be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: *(Shrug ...)* "These things do happen!" Have a look at the server-logs produced by the web-server at the remote site!  "It's an entirely different computer, after all, with its own local point-of-view."  Such problems are "easy to solve, but annoying."

Comment: Are the links requesting pages in a subdirectory? What if you referenced the index page as root in your RewriteRule to avoid possible confusion: `http://public/index.php`. Make sure no conflicting .htaccess files in a subdirectory.

Comment: `DirectoryIndex` line is not right. Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser?

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable the use of .htaccess files on the remote server? I doubt it's that Mod_rewrite is not enabled because you'd get a 500 internal server error so most likely your .htaccess is not getting read at all.

Check your vhost config and make sure you have

```
AllowOverride All
```